# Critical rationalism and Evolution

Tags: kant, critique-of-pure-reason

Lets assume I. Kant would have became aware of Darwins theory of Evolution after writing his "Kritik der reinen Vernunft". How could the knowledge have affected his idea about the "ursprünglich synthetische Einheit der transzendentalen Apperzeption"? Especially how could it have affected his notion of transcendence? Since adaptation would suggest that our cognitive apparatus developed itself under influence of the phenomena. Or alternatively is there the possibility that he could maintain his approach?

(Please forgive my naive question, I am not an educated philosopher).

Comment: He has a short note in his *third* critique (Critique of the Power of Judgement/Kritik der Urteilskraft) where he notes that both our theoretical understanding in general and the thought of nature evolving purposefully are a feature of our specific set of cognitive faculties. Could you try to specify *why* you think there would be a problem?

Comment: We can not really answer a counterfactual. The closest you can get is to look at how [neo-Kantians](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/neo-kantianism/) (Cohen, Natorp, Cassirer) adapted since they lived after Darwin, but tried their best to preserve Kantianism: "*This appreciation for the historically evolving character of culture has two consequences. First, the transcendental a priori is not absolute, but relative... Second... emphasis on the objectivity and lawlikeness of cultural change thus introduces a check on the potential relativistic or historicist consequences.*"

Comment: Please translate the phrase beginning with “ursprünglich” and provide a citation.

Comment: @MarkAndrews: For example KdrV, Elementarlehre I, Teil I, Abteilung I, Buch II, Hauptstück, §16 "von der ürsprünglich-synthestischen Einheit der Apperzeption". My own literal translation would be "original". I am not an expert on English translations of Kants' works.

Comment: @MarkAndrews "Of the Originally Synthetical Unity of Apperception § 12" in https://www.gutenberg.org/files/4280/4280-h/4280-h.htm#chap28 (J. M. D. Meiklejohn )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kant never denied that our cognitive apparatus is under the influence of phenomena, i.e. objects of our senses. He gives an account of our cognitive capacities from a strictly empirical point of view in his *Anthropology from a pragmatic point of view*. Here he also speaks of development of cognitive capacities through acquiring language which quite unequivocally tells us that he wouldn't find anything shocking about these ideas of Darwin. It's a common misconception about Kant to think that things-in-themselves are somehow completly alien to phenomena. Phenomena are objects insofar as they are intuited by us, things in themselves are the same objects if we abstract from any particular form of sensibility (space and time, in our case).

Comment: Hi and welcome abracadabra! I am glad that someone can answer all those questions on Kant which have been pending for a long time. Since your explanations are quite rigorous and you seem to have a good knowledge of the organisation of Kant's thought among its many works, it would be even better if you could quote the relevant portion from the works you cite. It really gives more insight for the readers as well as help this SE getting closer to academical quality (its still far-away but ideal goal). I'm looking forward to read all of those answers to understand Kant better.

Comment: @Johan Sure. But I don't think I can really provide any references for the fact that Kant's Anthropology discusses these matters from a strictly empirical point of view. I can however give a reference for the phenomena/noumena distinction, you're correct.

Comment: Oh sure, this was more of a general remark after seeing in your other answers some references to Kant's work for which you seem to have a precise quote in mind.